# can't get logcat to work android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-logcat, ddms

I've been trying to figure out why my app isn't working, but I can't find Logcat!  I just uploaded the new Android Studio release.  I've researched and found out where to look to get this message:

ddms: Can't bind to local 8610 for debugger

All the answers I see on SO are for Eclipse.  I looked at the developer page, yet for DDMS, it sends you to another page that is full of information for running DDMS in Eclipse!

Please, need some help here!  I mean if the dev page is wrong, can't someone show a little love?  (Instead of knocking me down 4 points like yesterday.  should left in the note I couldn't find my logcat but I was embarrassed.... now not so much ....  )

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had to open the Android Device Manager to get at the Logcat.  It would not scroll through the regular window when the app quit working like it used to (previous to yesterday's and today's updates to Android Studio).  As such, I cannot copy and paste code, but can use snagit to capture pngs to post.  Thank you. This question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have hided it...If it is hiding problems the go through given image to display it or ALT + 6

[image]